# GKE - How to use HTTPS on the Gateway in Jhipster 6 Microservice UAA project

Tags: jhipster, google-kubernetes-engine, jhipster-registry

I need some guidance please, first here is my project details :

```
- Jhipster v6.0.0
- Angular
- Microservices architecture with Jhipster-Registry + UAA
- No monitoring, no Ingress, no Istio (just the defaults options, full JHipster)
- Deployed on Google Kubernetes Engine cluster
```

So, if I understand correctly, with my current setup it is the Gateway that is doing the load balancing using Netflix Ribbon and it is the entry point from the World Wide Web to access my app. 
 How can I make my app accessible with HTTPS and SSL certificate on GKE ? I'm a bit confused, do I need to switch to Ingress ?

Thanks